# Nifi InvokeHTTP processor not triggering response relationship

Tags: apache-nifi

Consider the following flow which authenticates via HTTP to a service. I'm seeing an HTTP status code of `201` (created) come back, which should trigger the `response` relationship/flow. However as you can see in the log below, only the `original` relationship is triggered.

#### The Flow

Green lines indicate "response" flow. Magenta indicates "original" flow.

[image: Flow]

#### `POST /token` properties

[image: InvokeHTTP Properties]

#### Log

You can see here that the `original` relationship is triggered, but the `response` is not -- even though the status code, `201`, is in the "success" range.

```
2023-01-29 15:22:08,341 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=fe0ace38-0185-1000-376d-8737d0e020f8] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6b9f010a-f287-449c-8bef-94840c5cfa2f,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1674862641879-1, container=default, section=1], offset=13494, length=107],offset=0,name=6b9f010a-f287-449c-8bef-94840c5cfa2f,size=107]
---------------------ORIGINAL---------------------
FlowFile Properties
Key: 'entryDate'
        Value: 'Sun Jan 29 15:22:07 UTC 2023'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
        Value: 'Sun Jan 29 15:22:07 UTC 2023'
Key: 'fileSize'
        Value: '107'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
        Value: '6b9f010a-f287-449c-8bef-94840c5cfa2f'
Key: 'invokehttp.request.duration'
        Value: '738'
Key: 'invokehttp.request.url'
        Value: '...'
Key: 'invokehttp.response.url'
        Value: '...'
Key: 'invokehttp.status.code'
        Value: '201'
Key: 'invokehttp.status.message'
        Value: ''
Key: 'invokehttp.tx.id'
        Value: 'efca13ac-16a1-4a27-a8e1-d04110d48523'
Key: 'mime.type'
        Value: 'application/json'
Key: 'path'
        Value: './'
Key: 'responseBody'
        Value: '...'
Key: 'uuid'
        Value: '6b9f010a-f287-449c-8bef-94840c5cfa2f'
---------------------ORIGINAL---------------------
```

---

The only thing I though of which might be causing an issue is that I'm writing the response body to an attribute. I tried to test by setting this attribute name to empty string but that just gives me an error in the log. I assumed that without the attribute name set, the response body would be the FlowFile sent to the response relationship, but that doesn't seem to be working.

**Update:** I created a second `InvokeHTTP` processor and replaced the relationships / disabled the old one. The flow worked correctly until I set the `Response Body Attribute Name`, and then the `response` relationship stopped triggering. I need to set this attribute though, so I can extract the error message from the response in the case of failure. I think I'll have to enable the `Response Generation Required` option, and check the status code in the `response` relationship flow. This is not ideal, though.

Comment: It should be about your API response is null. Because when you want to take response on attribute, InvokeHTTP checks "bodyExists" flag.  **if (outputBodyToRequestAttribute && bodyExists)**

Comment: There is a JSON response to this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use **Response Body Attribute Name**, only original route is triggered. It's InvokeHTTP's behaviour, you can check [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html).

*FlowFile attribute name used to write an HTTP response body for FlowFiles transferred to the Original relationship.*

You can use this way for your problem,

```
InvokeHTTP (original route)-> RouteOnAttribute - (Success - ${invokehttp.status.code.ge(200):and(${invokehttp.status.code.le(299)})})
```

When you set **Response Body Attribute Name** attribute, it means that you don't want new flowfile, you want just add a new attribute to existing flowfile.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the docs but they are not clear in this regard. Even the quote you pasted above is not clear.